# Why doesn't Excel recognize =SUM(B2*C2*100:B3*C3*100)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to calculate my total expenditure on options contracts. Each contract = 100 shares.

[image]

Comment: Colon seems to be used to specify the data range in your formula. I suggest you  change the colon to a semicolon or a comma [link] (https://www.excel-exercise.com/comma-or-semicolon-in-excel-formula/), then SUM function will calculate the sum of `B2*C2*100` and `B3*C3*100`.

Comment: What you are trying needs simple multiplication like `A2*B2*100`,  you may use `=SUM(A2*B2*100)` but `SUM` has no role ,, if you want to get over all total then use `=(A2*B2)*100+(A3*B3)*100` .

Comment: @RajeshS "SUM has no role"? Yes it does. What if B and C have many entries?

Comment: @Vast,, yes SUM doesn't have any great role but if used then no error! If Col B & C does have many entries then drag the formula down if looking for one to one otherwise U need to use the Range `{=(b2:b10*C2:C10*100)}` with an Array formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `SUM` expects a range of cells, not a formula to evaluate. `SUM` is not a complex operator and wants only to see a "list of things" it can add together.

You should use a fourth column such as D, name it something like "total expenditure" and put

```
=B2 * C2 * 100
```

In that cell D2 and drag it down. Then your `SUM` should be simply

```
=SUM(D2:D3)
```

---

If you really must do this in a single step then you can use an [array formula.](https://kb.nmsu.edu/75306)

In this case you need to change your operation order slightly.

In your cell type

```
=SUM(B2:B3*C2:C3*100)
```

And then instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will convert the formula to an array formula, shown with `{}` surrounding the cell. After entering it should appear as

```
{=SUM(B2:B3*C2:C3*100)}
```

By this method the formula will be treated as an array, with each row in the array being multiplied across and *then* summed.

Answer (score 1):

The `SUM()` function can use cell references or constants or expressions.  If you need to add `100*B2*C2` to `100*B3*C3`then you don't need the `SUM()` function at all, just:

```
=100*(B2*C2+B3*C3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rearrange things a tad:

```
=SUM(B2:B3*C2:C3)*100  (Clearer for future work.)
```

or

```
=SUM(B2:B3*C2:C3*100)  (Might feel better to have it all inside, personal choice.)
```

Just specify the ranges as the basic items and put in the multiplier operator (or subtraction or... as needed, but you need multiplication today). So you are multiplying the ranges:  RANGE * RANGE, not cell sets inside the ranges by cell sets inside the ranges. As noted, `SUM()` likes ranges.

Then follow with the share lot size. If it differed, you'd have a somewhat different problem.

As noted by Gary's Student, if you really only have two items to multiply and sum (and need no future-proofing where you might have 87 to multiply and sum), just do the simple multiplication formula, no need to be fancy or work hard! But if it is currently more, or is expected to be, just do the above. Or if you just want to take the opportunity to enhance your skills via practice, use the above too. Practice does make perfect, or closer to one hopes.